# Cat peeing on couch learned behavior

Tags: cats, behavior, toilet-training, urination

I have two cats about 10 months old. I changed litterbox and litter around Christmas and within 2 weeks it became evident that they did not like the new litterbox situation, as they had pooped on the floor by the litterbox and had peed on the couch. I changed the litterbox back as well as got a second litter box to give them more space.

They stopped pooping on the floor; however, every once in a while (maybe once a week) they will pee on the couch, always in the same spot. The couch still has a slight smell despite using cleaner and I am planning to replace it, but I'm worried they will pee on the new couch. They aren't acting any different otherwise to indicate a medical issue and they are using the litter box (for pee and poop). This feels like a learned behavior that they picked up when they didn't like the litter box.

If I get the new couch and it doesn't smell, would they pee on it or are there any other things I can do to stop them from peeing? I was considering putting things on the couch to make it uncomfortable for them to stop them from peeing on it. Also I haven't been able to determine if it's both cats or just one cat peeing on the couch.

Comment: *"They aren't acting any different otherwise to indicate a medical issue"* Peeing in inappropriate places often is *the only* indication for a UTI you'll get from your cats. They instinctively hide their injuries and diseases until they are too weakened or too affected to hide them any longer. Peeing on the couch might be their way of saying "I don't like this litter", but it might also be their way of saying "peeing hurts me and I need you to notice this."